# Exporting string from SQL Server to csv

Tags: c#, sql-server, export-to-csv

```
public string statsString()
{
    string stats = "";

    //stats = getStat("Mean") + ", " + getStat("Median") + ", " + getStat("1st percentile") + ", " + getStat("3rd percentile");

    return stats;
}
```

I am trying to export the values to a `.csv` file, the values are being calculated through queries in SQL Server. I want to use `StreamWriter` but I am still very new to coding and am trying to help a friend export the values to a `.csv` file. The program is being written in c#. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: What would be the most practical way of reading those values?
Parsing?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has two great built in tool(s) to export data directly to an csv file. One way is to use the bcp command which runs from the command line and will very rapidly export data into an csv file.

The second way is to use SSIS which can be very sophisticated in the way you find and parse the data before exporting it into an CSV file. You can create an SSIS package through a built in GUI in SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS).

```
1) Right Click on the Database name in SSMS
2) Choose 'Tasks'
3) Click on 'Export Data'
4) Choose SQL Server Native Client for the Source Data and choose the database that containts the data to export
5) Choose Flat File for destination.
6) Follow the rest of the GUI....
4) Follow the Gui to export data
```